# Is there a slick way to test whether $\Bbb Z_{mn}\cong \Bbb Z_m\oplus \Bbb Z_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-product

I'm quite new to group theory, so apologies if this is a silly question to ask: it just interested me that 
$$\require{cancel}\Bbb Z_{4}\ncong\Bbb Z_2\oplus \Bbb Z_2$$
whereas
$$\Bbb Z_{6}\cong \Bbb Z_2\oplus \Bbb Z_3$$
For the first non-equation (I don't know the correct terminology to use here), since $\Bbb Z_2$ is a cyclic group of order $2$ it follows that each element in $\Bbb Z_2\oplus \Bbb Z_2$ has at most order $2$ and thus the isomorphism is impossible. But for the second equation, I cannot tell whether it's true at glance. I only know that the orders of elements in both LHS and RHS are $1,2,3,6$. I do not know whether RHS is cyclic till I write it explicitly, which is quite inefficient.

So I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this kind of problem in general: is there a know-it-at-first-glance method to tell whether 
$$\Bbb Z_{mn}\cong \Bbb Z_{m}\oplus \Bbb Z_{n}?$$
Or even more generally, what about 
$$\Bbb Z_{m_1m_2\cdots m_n}\cong \Bbb Z_{m_1}\oplus \Bbb Z_{m_2}\oplus\cdots\oplus\Bbb Z_{m_n}?$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: Please, note that the syntax `\Bbb Z` has been deprecated for 20 years in LaTeX and `\mathbb{Z}` is to be preferred.

Comment: No need to apologize: no legitimate question is silly.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I don't know this yet. I simply chose the one with less typesetting trouble..

Comment: @lhf Thank you sir. And thanks for your nice explanation as well.

Comment: @Vim If you plan to use LaTeX for producing your documents, it's better changing habits, so your input is valid on both LaTeX and MathJax. It's a nuisance that Math.SE doesn't accept `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`, though.

Comment: @egreg My LaTeX seems to accept \Bbb quite well.. I have not yet seen it cause any problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the mapping
$$
\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_m\oplus\mathbb{Z}_n
$$
defined by
$$
\varphi\colon x\mapsto (x+m\mathbb{Z},x+n\mathbb{Z})
$$
which is a group homomorphism.

Its kernel is
$$
\ker\varphi=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}:x\in m\mathbb{Z}, x\in n\mathbb{Z}\}
=m\mathbb{Z}\cap n\mathbb{Z}=k\mathbb{Z}
$$
where $k$ is the lowest common multiple of $m$ and $n$.

Thus $\varphi$ induces an injective homomorphism
$$
\tilde\varphi\colon \mathbb{Z}/\ker\varphi=\mathbb{Z}_k
\to\mathbb{Z}_m\oplus\mathbb{Z}_n
$$
which is surjective if and only if $k=mn$, by looking at the number of elements in the domain and codomain, that is, $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Conversely, it's easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}_m\oplus\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not cyclic if $\gcd(m,n)>1$, so it can't be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$.

Generalize to any (finite) number of factors.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a nice rule that says
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{n}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_m \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{mn}
$$
if and only if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.

Also, the external direct product $\oplus$ is associative, so $A\oplus (B\oplus C) \simeq (A\oplus B) \oplus C$. So the result extends to the more general case that you consider.

Comment: It's associative up to isomorphism, not literally associative.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Right, so as I write $A\oplus (B\oplus C) \simeq (A\oplus B) \oplus C$. It is common to identify groups that are isomorphic.

Comment: Ever since I was awakened to the fact that isomorphic things aren't necessarily exactly the same I've been picky about this. It was a very harmful misunderstanding when I took algebraic topology. Anyway, I suppose I can forgive you *this* time :P.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Yeah, when I teach Abstract Algebra I usually make a big deal about the differences between being isomorphic and equal. But I then soften up and we start saying things like: "There is only one group of order one". Likewise, I usually say that the (external) direct product is associative.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\Bbb Z_m\oplus \Bbb Z_n$ has order $mn$ and exponent $lcm(m,n)$ (that is, every element has order at most $lcm(m,n)$).

Therefore, $\Bbb Z_m\oplus \Bbb Z_n$ cannot be cyclic unless $lcm(m,n)=mn$, and this is equivalent to $gcd(m,n)=1$.

Thus, if $gcd(m,n)>1$, then $\Bbb Z_{mn}\not\cong \Bbb Z_m\oplus \Bbb Z_n$.

The converse is also true, and is the subject of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.