# Isomorphism between finite groups

Tags: finite-groups, group-isomorphism

What can be the general statements made, when two finite groups can be isomorphic to each other: $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$

Say 
$$\mathbb{Z}_{pq} \simeq\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q},$$

what are the conditions for $p$ and $q$ and their factorization relations?

How do we show this in the most elegant way? And the intuitive way?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490608/is-there-a-slick-way-to-test-whether-bbb-z-mn-cong-bbb-z-m-oplus-bbb-z-n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a slick way to test whether $\Bbb Z_{mn}\cong \Bbb Z_m\oplus \Bbb Z_n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490608/is-there-a-slick-way-to-test-whether-bbb-z-mn-cong-bbb-z-m-oplus-bbb-z-n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general result is

> $\Bbb Z_m \times \Bbb Z_n \cong \Bbb Z_{\gcd(m,n)} \times \Bbb Z_{\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)}$

(see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724407/bbb-z-m-times-bbb-z-n-isomorphic-to-bbb-z-operatornamelcmm-n-times) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205618/abstract-algebra))

In particular,

> $\Bbb Z_m \times \Bbb Z_n \cong \Bbb Z_{mn} $ when $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Adapted from https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2483130/589

Comment: how do we know this is the most general result? thanks +1.

Comment: @annieheart, there is almost never *the* most general result. In the context of your question, a major general result is the [fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification).